# How Flask default route avoid redirect?

Tags: angularjs, redirect, flask

I hava a list page:

```
$routeProvider.when('/', {
    redirectTo:'/1',            // so default will be page 1
}).when('/:page',{
    controller:'listCtrl',
    templateUrl:'xxxxx'
})
```

In the controller will use $route.current.params.page to do the logic.

The question is:redirectTo will cause a browser 301 which I don't want.(bad performance) And I also don't want everytime one click the main nav button, it would cause a 301.

How can I archive the same goal without use redirectTo?

It's something like: if I use the route same as '/:page'（write the same controller / templateUrl）, how can I pass the page number(1) to the controller without route param?

**EDIT:**

Thanks to the accepted answer.

Changed the title to Flask related.

Found that the 301 was caused by Flask's defaults route:

```
@bp.route('/list', defaults={'page':1})
@bp.route('/list/<int:page>')
def lst(page):
```

when the request uri is /list/1, will be 301 to /list... don't know how to resolve yet, but this is another question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`redirectTo` in `$route` doesn't actually do an HTTP redirect - it just redirects logically to the right `ng-view`. So, there isn't any performance hit.

But just for completeness-sake, you can pass a parameter in the `resolve` property:

```
.when('/:page?',{
    controller:'listCtrl',
    templateUrl:'xxxxx',
    resolve: {
      page: function($route) { return $route.current.params.page || 1; }
    }
})
```

Comment: Found that the 301 was caused by Flask, question edited, thanks